# para que sirve la clase LOG

Tags: spring, spring-boot

estuve revisando codigo, y veo todas partes la clase LOG

es para loguearse?

```
 @Component
class ApplicationEventListener {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationEventListener.class);
```

e invoca a la misma clase.

estoy usando Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, la clase Logger pertenece a slf4j (https://www.slf4j.org/), un api que sirve para la implementación de distintos sistemas de creación de trazas en las aplicaciones.

Este tipo de sistemas permite al programador conocer el estado de la ejecución de un programa sin necesidad de realizar un debug, ya que escriben líneas en un fichero de texto o en la consola donde se ejecuta la aplicación cada vez que se invoca a esas líneas de las que hablas.

Es uno de los pilares fundamentales en el mantenimiento de las aplicación. No dejes de leer (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) log4j o (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html) apache commons log; dos de los sitemas más conocidos de generación de trazas.

Answer (score 1):

No, esa clase es para mostrar mensajes de log, para poder controlar errores en la aplicación.

Un uso bastante simple, y siguiendo con la declaración que tú pones, podría ser:

```
LOG.debug("Esto es un mensaje de debug");
```

Saludos.